# what instance name in connection string for Dynamic management Views

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I want to run the following query ::

```
SELECT S.*
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests S
  JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions R ON r.session_id = s.blocking_session_id
```

It works when i run it in SQL Server Console.
But I haven't been able to do the same thru code.  I am using the following connection string:

```
"Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Master;Integrated Security = True"
```

Till now I have used `sys` and `MsSQLSystemResource` in the place of Master in the connection string ; But i am facing same error which says that there is problem connecting .. instance name could be wrong ..

Comment: What about creating a view in a database you created (rather than system ones), setting the connection string to that database, then query the view?  I wouldn't expect `SYS` to work as the initial catalog...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a view in a database you created (rather than system ones), setting the connection string to that database, then query the view.